# I want to send the data that has been url encoding in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, urlencode, jsr223

I want to send a data that has been encryption.
So, I used JSR223 Sampler.

---skip---

def encrypted = Crypto.encrypt("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "{"MY_SENTENCE"}", Crypto.generateSecretKey(), Crypto.generateIv())

vars.put("enc_data", encrypted);

---

Body Data in HTTP Request.

---

{ "data": "${enc_data}" }

---

In Results Tree
Request Body data was not url-encoding.

I want to send a data of url encoding, what should I do?
I don't know that.

I wrote Body Data in HTTP Request. So, I can't click the Parameters.

And I added Content encoding (UTF-8) it was not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use [__urlencode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function in the Body Data tab directly:

```
{ "data": "${__urlencode(${enc_data})}" }
```

[JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) can be placed anywhere in the test plan and they're evaluated in the place where they're present so your `${enc_data}` variable will be url-encoded in the runtime. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

or call [URLEncoder.encode() function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) in your Groovy script directly:

```
vars.put("enc_data", URLEncoder.encode(encrypted,"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I solved the problem. I also referred to code of other part in your other question answers. Thank you. I learned a lot.